# How to create a generic wrapper for just any method call?

Tags: java, spring, generics, project-reactor, spring-reactive

I want to create a helper method that can wrap/convert just **any** sync method call into an async `Mono`.

The following is close, but shows an error:

```
Required type: Mono <T>
Provided: Mono<? extends Callable<? extends T>>
```

This is my code:

```
public <T> Mono<T> wrapAsync(Callable<? extends T> supplier) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> supplier)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}

public void run() {
    Mono<Boolean> mono = wrapAsync(() -> syncMethod());
}

private Boolean mySyncMethod() {
    return true; //for testing only
}
```

Comment: If `Mono.fromCallable` takes a `Callable`, then `(() -> supplier)` is the wrong argument (it's more like a `Callable<Callable<T>>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you call Mono.fromCallable with a Callable<Callable<? extend T>>. You need to change the call like this: `Mono.fromCallable(supplier)`.

Then you will have a problem because Mono.fromCallable will be inferred as `Callable<? extend ? extend T>` so your Mono will be `Mono<? extend T>` instead of `Mono<T>`. To avoid this, two solutions:

1. Change the signature of wrapAsync:

```java
public <T> Mono<T> wrapAsync(Callable<T> supplier) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(supplier)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

2. Or if you want to keep the signature you need to provide type:

```java
public <T> Mono<T> wrapAsync(Callable<? extends T> supplier) {
    return Mono.<T>fromCallable(supplier)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

Comment: Okay, yes that makes sense. My problem was I though I'd have to provide the supplier itself also as a lambda call.